# Generating a changelog for an empty database with Liquibase in offline mode

Tags: java, postgresql, ant, liquibase

As the title says, I want to use Liquibase to generate a changelog for an empty database in offline mode. My ant file looks like the following:

```
<project xmlns:liquibase="antlib:liquibase.integration.ant">

<taskdef resource="liquibase/integration/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:liquibase.integration.ant">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="antlibs/liquibase-core-3.5.3.jar" />
        <pathelement location="antlibs/snakeyaml-1.18.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="generate-changelog">
    <liquibase:generateChangeLog>
        <liquibase:database url="offline:postgresql?snapshot=snapshot.json" />
        <liquibase:xml outputfile="target/changelog.xml" encoding="UTF-8" />
    </liquibase:generateChangeLog>
</target>
```

Later I want to add Liquibase-Hibernate4 to generate the changelog from my entities, but I encounter various issues beforehand. If I simply use the url "offline:postgresql", the ant task crashes with a NullPointerException, as Liquibase tried to clone the snapshot which is not available. If I add "?snapshot=snapshot.json", Liquibase (or Yaml) is not able to find my file.

My questions:

- Is this the right approach when I simply want to create the changelog for my entities without any base snapshot at all?
- Is there an easier way to provide liquibase with an empty database as base?
- How do I add the snapshot.json to the project to make sure, that the ant task can find it?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I was able to find out some things:

- To make sure that snapshot.json can be found by the task, one has to put it into a jar file and add the jar file to the task's class path.
- It does not seem to be the right approach for the Hibernate extension, as it seems that the Hibernate extension does not work with offline URLs.
- According to https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2183, a possible workaround would be to use an empty H2 database as a base to generate the initial JPA changelogs.